# Hello, I have A problem about geometry.

Tags: geometry

To prove that BO is perpendicular to AC

[image]

Comment: While I don't have a solution right now, I imagine that one method of proof could be a vector argument based on the sides of the triangle and squares.

Comment: Before the question was edited, the asker did specifically say *"please not with calculation"* - I'm not sure what this refers to, but maybe it means that he just wants some hints. From my side: The angles AEC and ACE are equal. The angles CFA and AFC are equal. Assigning names to the intersections of AB/EC and CB/AF may be helpful, as well as naming the foot of the perpendicular from B to AC. Then, you will have many congruent triangles, and I assume that the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem may applied to find the proof.

Comment: The problem is: the angles AEC and ACE are NOT equal... It is the case only if AC and AE are equal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend the side $AC$ into a line $\ell$.
Drop a perpendicular from $B$ to $\ell$ and let the foot be $H$.
Drop a perpendicular form $F$ to $\ell$ and let the foot be $I$.
Let the line segment $AF$ intersect $BH$ at $J$.

Let $\alpha = |AH|$, $\beta = |HC|$ and $\gamma = |BH|$. Since $BCFG$ is a square, we
have $|CI| = \gamma$ and $|FI| = \beta$. As a result,

$$|HJ| = |FI|\frac{|AH|}{|AI|} = \frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}$$
Notice this expression is symmetric with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$. If we exchange
the roles of $A$ and $C$ in above construction, the line segment $EC$ will intersect $BH$ at the same point $J$. This implies $J$ is the point $O$ in original question and hence $BO = BJ$ is perpendicular to $AC$.

[image: A tale of two squares]

Comment: Thank you. it is the best solution i saw for it